# Gearman and Wordpress wp-blog-header.php Access to wordpress functions

Tags: php, wordpress, client, worker, gearman

I'm trying to access wordpress functions inside of a gearman worker command line php script.

However when I include the require for wp-blog-header or wp-load.php, the gearman worker script just hangs, no output after the include is reached or written to the screen.

When I take out the wp-blog-header include, the gearman worker works fine and when a gearman client is loaded, gearmand does its thing.  And if I do the reverse, take out the gearman code and just use wp-blog-header.php, I have access to the wordpress functions.

It just hangs on the gearman worker.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What WP functions do you need? You are aware that the `.php` files you mentioned pull a truckload of WP-specific stuff, right?

Comment: Is debug set to true? Do you see any error code in the file source?

Comment: The wp function that im after is WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance, then WP_Session_Tokens::destroy_all().  Gearmand debug mode is turned on, and logs to gearmand.log, but when including the wordpress files, nothing is logged in /usr/local/var/log/gearmand.log.  display_errors is turned on and error reporting is set to E_ALL.

Comment: if I uncomment the line $worker->addServer( "127.0.0.1" );  echo's after the wordpress include work but obviously not the gearmand worker.

Comment: nothing in the php error log as well

Comment: not sure whats going on, at the moment i add require wp-load, either at the beginning or near end of the script, nothing after the require is echoed out or invoked. no errors are logged to the error_log

Answer (score 0):

Well since I couldn't get the require to work inside the same script as the gearman worker, I used exec() to an external script that required the wp-load.php. I also pass parameters from the worker script to the external wp-load script using $argv.